# autowire byType according to Spring 4.1.6 to Documentation

Tags: spring, spring-4

*Allows a property to be autowired if exactly one bean of the property type exists in the container. If more than one exists, a fatal exception is thrown, which indicates that you may not use byType autowiring for that bean. If there are no matching beans, nothing happens; the property is not set. - FROM [SPRING REFERENCE GUID 4.1.6](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-exceptions)*

```
<bean id="person" class="autowire.Person" autowire="byType" />

<bean id="invisible" class="autowire.Ability" >
    <property name="skill" value="Invisible" />
</bean>

<bean id="invisible2" class="autowire.Ability" >
    <property name="skill" value="Invisible" />
</bean>
```

Class Definitions:

```
package autowire;

public class Person 
{
private Ability ability;
//...
}

package autowire;

public class Ability {

    private String skill;

    public String getSkill() {
        return skill;
    }

    public void setSkill(String skill) {
        this.skill = skill;
    }

}
```

I was able to define 2 beans of same type of class "autowire.Ability". I didnt get the Fatal exception. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Does your person have a `setAbility` method? As you now only have a field not a property.

Comment: So a field and property are different ? i thought a POJO's member variable is a property.

Comment: Nope, I suggest a read of the Java Bean Specification.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there (to get the error). You need to tell spring which class attributes need to be autowired. Annotate `Person.ability` with @Autowired and you should get the error.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Person 
{
  @Autowired
  private Ability ability;
  //...
}
```

Or even better create a constructor and autowire it, as injecting attributes is considered a bad practice.

```
public class Person 
{
  private Ability ability;

  @Autowired
  public Person(Ability ability) {
    this.ability = ability;
  }
  //...
}
```

Spring doesn't assume which attributes need to be injected (autowired) so you need to specify which ones you want to inject.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing is correct, you can define as many beans of the same type as you want, problem arises when an `Autowired bean`(Component, Service, etc), expects a dependency of certain type and it cannot resolved because there are many that matches the field definition, for example:

If `Person` is declared as a `@Component` and declare an `@Autowired` field of type `Ability`, for example:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Person {
    @Autowired
    private Ability ability;
}
```

Having the two beans `invisible` and `invisible2` would cause the expected exception because Spring won't be able to know which of the two beans need to be injected in `Person`.

To run this example you will need to enable a Scan application context.

Hope this helps,

José Luis